# Using Pandas to read in txt file using delimiters creates NaNs columns

Tags: pandas, text, import

I am trying to read in a text file into pandas but its creating NaNs for all for all of the rows. I tried to use a delimiter to break up the variables that are separated by a \ but this is not working correctly. Here is what the data file looks like in the text file

Data:

```
Date         Name          Group    Direction
2015-01-01  Smith.John      -          In
2015-01-01  Smith.Jan       Claims     Out
2015-01-01     -            Claims     In
2015-01-01  Smith.Jessica   Other      In
```

Here is my first attempt to read in the data:

```
pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\skills.txt',
        names=['Date','AgentName','Group','Direction'])
```

However, this produce

```
    Date    AgentID     AssignedWorkGroup   CallDirection
 0  Date\tAgentID\tAssignedWorkGroup\tCallDire...   NaN     NaN     NaN
 1  2015-09-01\Smith.John\t-\tIn                    NaN     NaN     NaN
```

So I tried to get rid of the \ by doing:

```
 pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\skills.txt',
         names=['Date','AgentName','Group','Direction'],delimiter='\\')
```

But this still produces the same results. So couple of things. One is that I can't break out the '\'. Additionally, looks like the first row getting read in are the headers. I tried using header=None to get rid of them but that didn't work out too well for me either. It also appears that their is a t (I assume for text?) being place in front of every variable

I feel as though I am approaching this incorrectly

Comment: You're specifying column names but this confuses the parser as it's interpreting the first line as data, also it looks you have tab separated values. Try this: `pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\skills.txt',
        names=['Date','AgentName','Group','Direction'], skiprows=1, sep='\t')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you passed the alternate column names this means that the csv parser is interpreting the first row as a valid data row so you need to pass `skiprows=1` to skip your header, additionally the default separator is comma `,` but it looks like your data is either tab or multi-space separated so you can pass `sep='\t'` or `sep='\s+'`.

It's unclear if your data is tab or space separated but the following worked for me:

```
In [18]:
t="""Date         Name          Group    Direction
2015-01-01  Smith.John      -          In
2015-01-01  Smith.Jan       Claims     Out
2015-01-01     -            Claims     In
2015-01-01  Smith.Jessica   Other      In"""
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), names=['Date','AgentName','Group','Direction'], skiprows=1, sep='\s+')

Out[18]:
         Date      AgentName   Group Direction
0  2015-01-01     Smith.John       -        In
1  2015-01-01      Smith.Jan  Claims       Out
2  2015-01-01              -  Claims        In
3  2015-01-01  Smith.Jessica   Other        In
```

so I expect

```
pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\skills.txt', names=['Date','AgentName','Group','Direction'], skiprows=1, sep='\t')
```

or

```
pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\skills.txt', names=['Date','AgentName','Group','Direction'], skiprows=1, sep='\s+')
```

to work for you

Answer (score 0):

Using whitespace as delimeter works:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\skills.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
df.columns = ['Date','AgentName','Group','Direction']
```

Output:

```
         Date      AgentName   Group Direction
0  2015-01-01     Smith.John       -        In
1  2015-01-01      Smith.Jan  Claims       Out
2  2015-01-01              -  Claims        In
3  2015-01-01  Smith.Jessica   Other        In
```